# How connect logstash to padrino framework

Tags: ruby, logstash, padrino

I need to make logging with logstash in Padrino project. I setup logstash on remote server and tried to integrate it with Padrino project, I found only one solution

`logger = LogStashLogger.new(type: :udp, host: host, port: 5044) if RACK_ENV = 'staging'`

but it can working only when use this code `logger.debug message: 'test', foo: 'bar'`

Can I make that all logs automatically will send to remote server?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Padrino::Logger.logger = LogStashLogger.new(type: :udp, host: host, port: 5044)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
Padrino::Logger.logger = LogStashLogger.new(type: :udp, host: '172.16.x.x', port: 9999).extend(Padrino::Logger::Extensions)
```

Comment: You need to explain why the code works, just a string of codes is not well received as an answer.